# Are you billed for a Google Places AutoComplete session if the user doesn't type in the textbox?

Tags: google-places-api, billing

I'm trying to decide if it's worth the cost to add Google Places AutoComplete to our customer address forms.  We have 5 places users could see this.  I would say on average, they may see it twice in a session.

Google's documentation says a session starts with the first request and ends when the place is selected, or the user doesn't make a selection for 3 minutes.

What it doesn't say is if I include the widget but the user doesn't make any requests, am I billed for a session.  This makes about an 75% usage difference.

Anyone have stats on this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a technical question, but to answer this, you will not be billed if the user will not type anything.

You will only be billed once you make successful Places Autocomplete requests (which is triggered when the user starts typing) or make successful Place Details requests (which is triggered when a user selects a place from the suggestions). If you only include the widget, but not make any API requests, then you will not be charged.

Please see more info here about [Places API Autocomplete sessions](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use#about-autocomplete-sessions).

Hope this helps!